# React memo get magically executed twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm creating a react app with `useMemo`.
The memo uses empty array as the dependency list, so it should be executed once, right?

Inside the memo, there are `console.log()` & `counter++` to visualize how many times the memo get executed.

Magically, I got **one log** but the counter seems **executed twice**.

[See this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-y7p99?file=/src/App.js) or see the code below:

```
import {
    useMemo,
}                           from 'react'


let counter = 0;
export default function App() {
    const foo = useMemo(() => {
        console.log('increase counter');

        counter++;
    }, []);


    return (
        <p>
            {counter}
        </p>
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check this link: [usememo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17186#issuecomment-546553979)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're incorrectly using `useMemo`

A `useMemo()` computes something only when something in its dependancy array changes. It looks like you haven't given the dependancy array any variables.

Please review this example of `useMemo`:

```
export default function App() {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const component = useMemo(() => {
    if(loading){
  return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
  return <div>Finished Loading</div>
}, [loading]);


return (
    <div>
        {component}
    </div>
);
}
```

As you can see from this example when the state changes the useMemo is computed.

In your above example, I imagine the useMemo is being computed twice because its happening each time the page renders.

For your counter example I would recommend just using useState.

```
 export default function App() {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

return (
    <div>
        <p>{counter}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCounter(prevState => prevState++)}>Increase Counter</button>
    </div>
);
}
```

**EDIT:** This question was actually resolved in the comments. Disabling StrictMode prevents the double re-render.

Comment: Yes i know i'm abusing the `useMemo`, it should use `use(Layout)Effect`. It's the investigation why my code got executed twice, so i created the code above to inspect whats happened. Then i realized the memo got executed twice.

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer, apologies for not being clearer. Your code is being computed twice as something is causing your page to render twice. Its also not recommended to use useMemo without a dependancy array as it cause unstable side effects

Comment: i've tested by modifying `const somethingNeverMutated = {}`  and `[somethingNeverMutated]`. Since the dependency is never changed, the memo should executed once but got twice.

Comment: I added `console.log("render");` before the `return <p>...<p>` and i got one render log. So i belived the page rendered once.

Comment: i've commented all the logs and got the counter = 2

Comment: I've found this duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549481/react-render-twice-with-hooks

Comment: I think turning off StrictMode may resolve your issue.

Comment: i suspected the react **secretly** executes the second memo while disabling the log function.

Comment: oh yess, finally the `<StrictMode></StrictMode>` is the root of my problem. I don't know why react doing this.