# dupe rendering in console react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Why is this duplicating in the console? I noticed this while working on another projects and noticed the amount of HTML elements I was adding using jQuery was twice as much as expected (building a notification framework). I tried recreating the problem in a new project and the behavior persisted

**DupeMountTest.js:**

```
import React, {Component, useEffect} from "react";

const DupeMountTest = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect")
    }, [])

    return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
    )
}

export default DupeMountTest
```

**App.js:**

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import DupeMountTest from "./DupeMountTest";

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path={"/"} exact element={<DupeMountTest/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Console:**

[image]

I also attempted this using a class component but "Mounted" also logged twice.

*DupeMountTest* using class component:

```
import React, {Component, useEffect} from "react";

class DupeMountTest extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Mounted")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DupeMountTest
```

Comment: It’s strict mode. It renders everything twice

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by evolutionxbox inside the comments section. Problem solved by removing `<React.StrictMode>` in `index.js`:

Updated index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  //
  // </React.StrictMode>
    <App />
);
```

Comment: StrictMode is there for a really good reason. Do not remove it systematically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount.

Answer (score 0):

> React 18 introduces a new development-only check to Strict Mode. This
> new check will automatically unmount and remount every component,
> whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous
> state on the second mount.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

So, your `useEffect` is running twice on each mount.

This was put in place to lay the groundwork for future features, so it's not exactly a bad thing.

> In the future, we’d like to add a feature that allows React to add and
> remove sections of the UI while preserving state. For example, when a
> user tabs away from a screen and back, React should be able to
> immediately show the previous screen. To do this, React would unmount
> and remount trees using the same component state as before.
>
> This feature will give React apps better performance out-of-the-box,
> but requires components to be resilient to effects being mounted and
> destroyed multiple times. Most effects will work without any changes,
> but some effects assume they are only mounted or destroyed once.

It's also discussed in this post (thanks @evolutionxbox):

[React Hooks render twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603209/react-hooks-render-twice)

I really liked a comment there that basically summed up the answer to what you're wondering about:

"it's a feature, not a bug."