# why does react useeffect function renders a console log twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning react useEffect().
In this example, "render" gets logged twice the first time I run the application.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const [resourceType, setResourceType] = useState("posts");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render");
  }, [resourceType]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setResourceType("posts")}>Posts</button>
        <button onClick={() => setResourceType("users")}>Users</button>
        <button onClick={() => setResourceType("comments")}>Comments</button>
      </div>
      <h1>{resourceType}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

It should render it once as the application is run.
Why is it printed twice in the console log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks render twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603209/react-hooks-render-twice)

Comment: Also, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is caused by React strict mode

***No need to worry***, this only happens with strict mode and should not occur in production builds. This behavior is considered normal, especially in local host or development. (read below to understand why)

### Explanation

In React Strict Mode, certain lifecycle methods, including render and effects, may be double-invoked for the purpose of detecting side-effects. This behavior is specific to development mode and is meant to help catch and log side-effect issues. It should not occur in production.

If the double-invocation is observed only in development mode, and your application works as expected in production, it's likely related to Strict Mode behavior.

### Solution

Don't worry about it when in development (strict mode), because everything is performing as expected

Answer (score 0):

So, when you click any of the buttons (`Posts`, `Users`, or `Comments`), it will cause a state change (`resourceType` updates), triggering a re-render of the component and resulting in the `useEffect` running again, logging "render" to the console.

By passing an empty dependency array (`[]`), the effect will only run once after the initial render, mimicking the behavior you described.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("render");
}, []);
```

Comment: No this is not true. The re-render is happening because of the new performance boost feature implemented in React 18. For ref: https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-strict-mode