# How do I best fix this issues where set state keeps adding 1 two times in my react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Why is the setPoints((prevPoint) => prevPoint + 1) in `useEffect` keeps adding 2 times almost immediately?

I've tried everything, how do I best fix this for it to print only once?

I am trying to check if the moving animation have gotten to a certain distance which is the value of `distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle`, so I can add one to the point state, but it keeps adding 1 two times almost immediately.

```
const theBallPosition = new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0});

const destinationY = distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle ? distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle : 0;

function movingBallFunction() {

  //const destinationY = ballAtTop ? distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle : 0;


  //This is linear animation
  Animated.timing(theBallPosition, {
    toValue: {x: 0, y: destinationY},//This the distance the ball should fall to
    duration: movingBallTimeDuration,//This is for the time the ball should reach the bigCircle
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,

  }).start();//This start() method starts our animation

  //This is to not show the instruction on how to start game when user
  //have started playing the game, or when the ball is moving already. .
  setShowHowToStartGameInstruction(false)
}

useEffect(() => {

  const animationListener = (value) => {

    if (value.y === distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle) {

      console.log('it has reach the finals,', value.y)

      return setPoints((prevPoint) => prevPoint + 1);  

    }

  };

  // Attach the listener
  const listenerId = theBallPosition.addListener(animationListener);

  // Cleanup mechanism: remove the listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    theBallPosition.removeListener(listenerId);
  };

}, [theBallPosition, distanceOfScreenTopToBigCircle])
```

Comment: why is it a problem that its logging 3 times exactly?

Comment: actually i want to do something like setPoints((prevPoint) => prevPoint + 1); in the if statement, and it will end up adding 3 times at once in my point state. so how do i solve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does react useeffect function renders a console log twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744538/why-does-react-useeffect-function-renders-a-console-log-twice)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the changes that React introduced with React v18. This is intentional by the React developers and is supposed to help catch hard to spot bugs during your development.

It happens when running in Strict Mode and is development only...essentially your component is unmounted and re-mounted automatically after the initial mounting.

Here's the React Blog's announcement for React v18: https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-strict-mode-behaviors

And here's an article about possibly fixing it: https://medium.com/@arm.ninoyan/fixed-react-18-useeffect-runs-twice-8480f0bd837f